# Repeated "Oops 0000 [#1] SMP" Crashes

Tags: 12.04, kernel, crash

My installation of Ubuntu 12.04 is repeatedly crashing to black screens. It crashes during a variety of activities (watching Youtube videos in Chrome, rendering video, watching other video, playing flash games, etc.)

I have seen the information on the Ubuntu Wiki for debugging this type of crash but am unsure how to collect the requested data, since A) the crashes happen with a variety of modules and B) I cannot easily save the output information.

I was only able to capture [the output of dmesg](http://pastebin.com/HXUyqHAN) once. The rest of the information I have gathered is in [this set of crudely capture screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzXFm.jpg).

The problem also occurs in a clean installation of Lubuntu 12.04, so I fear a hardware problem but am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace it looks like your hitting a kernel panic, possibly due to **referencing an invalid NULL pointer**.  Also from the screen shot shows a diffirent issue, related to a **unhandled paging request**. 
Its best to raise an issue/bug with this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Bugs) with the os vendor.

These could be a possibly bugs in the kernel version you are using as Ubuntu 12.04 has LTS if its shipped with the hardware. Also you could consider trying out Ubuntu 14.04 as an alternative.

Comment: 14.04 seems to work for the time being. I assembled the hardware myself, so I installed the 12.04 myself.

Comment: Glad to know! its always best to go with the latest version especially when you have newer hardware as the new versions comes with several bug fixes and improvements with the kernel and drivers.

Comment: The hardwares not particularly new, and I had it working previously. I'm not sure what I did that made it begin to crash.

Comment: possibly, were there any kernel updates ? or did you check for any errors from the syslog ?

Comment: Just so I'm sure, what is the path for the syslog?

Comment: It may be worth looking into all the files `/var/log/syslog*`